When reading environment variables in Python from Docker's --env-file argument, there is an added '\' to each '\n'. How to not have that extra '\'?
I'm in the process of containerizing my Python app. Normally, I'd load in my .env file and use dotenv to read in the variable.
Example:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os


def test_env():
    load_dotenv()
    print(f"private_key : {repr(os.environ.get('PRIVATE_KEY'))}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_env()

and in my .env file I'd have to have quotes around my variable for this to work too. Example:
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n.....=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

This gets printed out correctly in my Python application.
However, when I run the same code but using Docker's --env-file I get an extra \ added to each \n.
Example docker command:
docker run --env-file ./.env -d -p $(RUN_PORT):$(RUN_PORT) --name $(DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME) $(FULL_IMG_NAME)

The output looks like: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\n...=\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n'
This is regardless of whether the .env file has "" around the variable or not. All the "" does to the variable, is that literal to the variable, which is not the case with dotenv.
What needs to be done?

The issue isn't so much that a backslash is added, but more that \n is transformed into a newline character when you use dotenv. The Docker environment file does not do that, so the environment variable contains two characters, a backslash and an 'n'. And when your Python program prints that, it adds the extra backslash to escape the backslash. To fix it, you can replace \n with a newline character when reading the environment variable.

dotenv is not being used anymore since there's no .env file. Docker is injecting the env variables directly to the program. When I print using os.environ.get() I get the extra character.

The difference is that dotenv interprets \n and changes it to a newline character. os.environ.get does not, so it returns \n as two characters. Then, when you print it, repr escapes the backslash and adds an extra backslash.

Okay, I think I'm getting it now. I need to update the .env variable and replace the /n with a newline character?
By new line character do you mean literally having a new line in my variable in the .env file?

I tried putting newline characters in the environment file and couldn't get it to work. I think the best solution is to let Python process the escape characters. I've posted an answer showing how to do that.

dotenv processes the text and decodes escape sequences. So it replaces \n with a newline character.
os.environ.get doesn't, so your string contains two characters: a backslash and an 'n'. The repr function then escapes the backslash when you print it, so you get the double backslash you see.
You can process the escape sequences yourself in Python using the decode function like this
import os

def test_env():
    private_key = bytes(os.environ.get('PRIVATE_KEY'), "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
    print(f"private_key : {repr(private_key)}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_env()

That should read the private key from the environment variable and change \n to newlines like you're used to dotenv doing.

Dang, so I'll have to do this for every environment variable to make sure I don't have escaping characters? Will try it out, thanks!
